# Visiting Costa Rica: How to prove sufficient funds?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, costa-rica, proof-of-funds

Upon visa-less immigration to Cost Rica, I would have to prove sufficient funds of $100 per month of residence ([Source](http://www.justlanded.com/english/Costa-Rica/Costa-Rica-Guide/Visas-Permits/Visas))

Since I don't expect them to have a dollar-giving ATM before immigration control at San Jose airport and my local currency is Euro, I wondered how I can prove that.

Euros are not accepted in Costa Rica I'd guess. Banks in my area could give me a $100 bill (but none of them could provide Colones yet), but does the next taxi driver have sufficient change to accept it? Or will immigration control accept any bank account report showing I have more than 100 Euro on it?

Comment: Don't know about Costa Rica specifically but usually countries do accept funds in well-known easily convertible currencies (if they bother checking at all, that is). They only use dollars (or euros or the local currency) to define the amount required. For example, in the Schengen area, “cash in convertible currency” is perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Living in Costa Rica is obviously really, really cheap.

Immigration will accept a wallet full of Euros as "proof of sufficient funds" - any decent bank will have no problem changing Euros, US Dollars or Pounds for Colones. Yuan, Rials, Baht and other currencies not printed in the roman alphabet are less likely.

The taxi driver won't take Euros, but the money exchange counter at any international airport serving Central America can give you enough local money to get you through the weekend. At the usual extortionary rates of course.

You could always take a couple of hundred US dollars, but get $10s or $20s. US$100 are frequently counterfeited, and in that part of the world will likely set off the drug detector.

Comment: This is also a good tip in general for that area: bring some dollars along which are likely to be accepted by taxi drivers etc. so you aren't reliant on the airport exchange places and can search for a non-extortionist one